# Oracle Universal Installer is stuck on step 7 out of 10

Tags: oracle, odac

I have a previous laptop where my c# code is connected to oracle database and had no problem when I installed there the Oracle Universal Installer.

But then it crashes and now I am transferring my project to a different laptop. Now when I tried to run my codes on the new laptop, it has now error such as below:

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception. ---> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.oracleException: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client

So what I did is I try to install the Oracle Universal Installer (the same installer I used from my previous laptop) ODAC 12.2.0.1.1 from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/dotnet-odacdev-downloads.html

But installation never ends. It stuck on Step 7 of 10. Please see screenshot here https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JcJA.jpg

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what the problem could be, there are several issues with the Oracle Installer.

Perhaps you have installed more than one Oracle Client. You should remove any existing clients entirely before you install **one** fresh Client. See [How to uninstall / completely remove Oracle 11g (client)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client) for help. You should not mix installations with Oracle Universal installer and ODAC, use only one type. I can be rather difficult to make them working together.

Before you launch the Oracle Universal installer clear TEMP files:

```
FOR /D %D in ( %TEMP%\deinstall* ) DO rmdir /S /Q %%D
FOR /D %D in ( %TEMP%\OraInstall* ) DO rmdir /S /Q %D
FOR /D %D in ( %TEMP%\CVU* ) DO rmdir /S /Q %D
```

Ensure you started the Oracle Universal Installer as Administrator. Ensure you install the same architecture (i.e. 32-bit vs. 64-bit) as your application.

Due to [Bug 17548895: CUSTOM INSTALL FAILS TO INCLUDE ORACLSCE12.DLL](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=1589205.1&id=17548895) you have to include component "Oracle Net" in your installation if you run "Custom Install"

Oracle 12.1 and higher does not register the **Oracle Data Provider for .NET** in the GAC anymore, see [Doc ID 2272241.1](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2272241_1.html). See [SSMA unable to find specified provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54020284/ssma-unable-to-find-specified-provider/54020739#54020739) for solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I had to disable antivirus system(Avast). Then it worked OK.