# Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017 installation failed to start

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2017, odp.net

I'm trying to install the Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017 on my computer for Visual Studio 2017 v15.9.5.

I'm using Windows 10 and the version of the universal installer I'm using is 18.3.

Once I download the zip file and unzip all the contents, I then run the 'setup.exe' executable.

Once I run it, it asks for admin privileges and I give them to the installation.

Immediately after that, a console window blinks on the screen and nothing else happens. No other UI shows up and I'm not asked any questions or provided any error messages.

I have restarted my machine and attempted to install with no success.

Any assistance for getting the setup running would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try setting the compatibility mode to an older OS like Windows 7 or XP and then run as administrator.

Comment: Have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57869219/oracle-universal-installer-is-stuck-on-step-7-out-of-10/57869857#57869857

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.
I was running the executable in a directory so far down the directory tree that all the paths the executable was using were greater than 260 characters in length, which Windows has an issue with.